# Walking an object on a terrain (made using heightmap) in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

To walk an object on terrain, currently I'm keeping the camera and the object fixed, and moving the terrain according to the keyboard button pressed (using glTranslatef). I'm able to move along x and z axis easily, but when I'm moving along y axis, I'm having a lot of trouble. Here is the essential parts of code:

I've made a class called Terrain which uses bmp file to get height at different points. The essential code is:

```
float Terrain::getHeight(int x, int z) {
    return hs[z][x];
}

Terrain* loadTerrain(const char* filename, float height) {
    Image* image = loadBMP(filename);
    Terrain* t = new Terrain(image->width, image->height);
    for (int y = 0; y < image->height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image->width; x++) {
            unsigned char color = (unsigned char) image->pixels[3
                    * (y * image->width + x)];
            float h = height * ((color / 255.0f) - 0.5f);
            t->setHeight(x, y, h);

        }
    }

    delete image;
    t->computeNormals();
    return t;
}
```

So basically I've stored them all in an array and can get y using x and z anytime. Here is my code for drawTerrain, which takes three float values, xx,yy and zz, and basically use glTranslatef to translate the terrain in xx and zz directions (I haven't used yy yet).

```
void drawTerrain(float xx, float yy, float zz, float aangle) {
    float yyy;
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(-aangle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(xx, yy, zz);

    GLfloat ambientColor[] = { 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientColor);

    GLfloat lightColor0[] = { 0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat lightPos0[] = { -0.5f, 0.8f, 0.1f, 0.0f };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureId1);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    float scale = 50.0f / max(_terrain->width() - 1, _terrain->length() - 1);
    glScalef(scale, scale, scale);
    glTranslatef(-(float) (_terrain->width() - 1) / 2, 0.0f,
            -(float) (_terrain->length() - 1) / 2);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    for (int z = 0; z < _terrain->length() - 1; z++) {
        //Makes OpenGL draw a triangle at every three consecutive vertices
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for (int x = 0; x < _terrain->width(); x += 2) {
            /*if (x == 0 && z == 0)
             glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
             if (x == _terrain->width() - 1 && z == 0)
             glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
             if (x == 0 && z == _terrain->length() - 1)
             glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
             if (x == _terrain->width() - 1 && z == _terrain->length() - 1)
             glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);*/
            Vec3f normal = _terrain->getNormal(x, z);
            glNormal3f(normal[0], normal[1], normal[2]);
            glTexCoord2f((float) x / _terrain->width(),
                    (float) z / _terrain->length());
            glVertex3f(x, _terrain->getHeight(x, z), z);
            normal = _terrain->getNormal(x, z + 1);
            glNormal3f(normal[0], normal[1], normal[2]);
            glTexCoord2f((float) x / _terrain->width(),
                    (float) (z + 1) / _terrain->length());
            glVertex3f(x, _terrain->getHeight(x, z + 1), z + 1);
            glNormal3f(normal[0], normal[1], normal[2]);
            glTexCoord2f((float) (x + 1) / _terrain->width(),
                    (float) z / _terrain->length());
            glVertex3f(x + 1, _terrain->getHeight(x + 1, z), z);
            glNormal3f(normal[0], normal[1], normal[2]);
            glTexCoord2f((float) (x + 1) / _terrain->width(),
                    (float) (z + 1) / _terrain->length());
            glVertex3f(x + 1, _terrain->getHeight(x + 1, z + 1), z + 1);

        }
        //_y = (float) _terrain->getHeight((int) (_x * max(_terrain->width() - 1, _terrain->length() - 1) / 50.0f), (int) (_z * max(_terrain->width() - 1, _terrain->length() - 1) / 50.0f));
        glEnd();
    }
```

So to translate in y direction, I've tried to use the following code:

```
float xxx,yyy,zzz;
xxx = (float) (_terrain->width() - 1) / (2 * scale);
xxx -= xx / scale;
zzz = (float) (_terrain->length() - 1) / (2 * scale);
zzz -= zz / scale;
yyy = scale * _terrain->getHeight(xxx,zzz);
glTranslatef(0.0f,yyy,0.0f);
```

But the translate is still not working according to height, and the y translate also does not looks continuous (since I'm converting integer and float values). Can anyone fix this code, or suggest some other method so that I can walk an object on terrain properly? Thanks.

Comment: Terrain  roaming usually involves ray casting.Google for it.Here we don't fix code ;)

Comment: I'm able to roam around terrain, the problem is to get height at a point. Using ray casting would mean completely changing my code :( Thanks anyway

Comment: Probably yes,but with ray casting it is easier to setup.

Comment: Have you looked at the values actually being stored inside the Terrain::hs array to be sure they aren't all the same?  Also, inside your last box where you're trying to do the y translation you use the 'xx' in both the xxx and zzz values.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: ^ Oops. I've fixed that part of code. And no, all the elements of the array are not same. But I'm still having a problem of heights being loaded at discrete level...

Comment: What is the value of **scale** you are using?  Is it possible the **scale** is such that the combination of the **gScalef** function and the height calculation you did when creating the height map makes the values so small as to be the same?